# Too many open files in Windows when writing multiple HDF5 files

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

My question is **how to close HDF5 files indefinitely after writing them**?

I am trying to save data to HDF5 files - there are around 200 folders and each folder contains some data for each day for this year.

When I retrieve and save data using pandas `HDFStore` with following code in iPython console, the function stop automatically after a while (no error msg).

```
import pandas as pd

data = ... # in format as pd.DataFrame
# Method 1
data.to_hdf('D:/file_001/2016-01-01.h5', 'type_1')
# Method 2
with pd.HDFStore('D:/file_001/2016-01-01.h5', 'a') as hf:
    hf['type_1'] = data
```

When I tried the same script to download data again, it says:

> [Errno 24] Too many open files: ...

There are some posts suggesting using **ulimit -n 1200** for example in Linux to overcome the problem, but unfortunately I'm using Windows.

Besides, I think I already close files explicitly using *with* closure, especially in *Method 2*. How come iPython still count these files as open?

My loop is sth like below:

```
univ = pd.read_excel(univ_file, univ_tab)
for dt in pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='B'):
    for t in univ:
        data = download_data(t, dt)
        with pd.HDFStore(data_file, 'a') as hf:
            # Use pd.DataFrame([np.nan]) instead of pd.DataFrame() to save space
            hf[typ] = EMPTY_DF if data.shape[0] == 0 else data
```

Comment: Both methods should properly close the store object, __after they finish__ (normally or with an exception). How many times did you re-start your script after it "stop automatically after a while"?

Comment: @MaxU thx. my script couldn't finish while they stopped **without exceptions**. When I try to run it again (it will pick up from where it stopped), the error [Errono 24] comes out and script stopped immediately. So if I want to run the script, I have to close the iPython console and restart it to be able to run

Comment: can you show a loop in which you're calling `.to_hdf()` or `pd.HDFStore()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check / list all open files belonging to Python process in Windows using `psutil` module.

Demo:

```
In [52]: [proc.open_files() for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.pid == os.getpid()]
Out[52]:
[[popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\en-US\\KernelBase.dll.mui', fd=-1),
  popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Max\\.ipython\\profile_default\\history.sqlite-journal', fd=-1),
  popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Max\\.ipython\\profile_default\\history.sqlite', fd=-1)]]
```

a file handler will be closed as soon as we are done with the following block:

```
In [53]: with pd.HDFStore('d:/temp/1.h5', 'a') as hf:
   ....:     hf['df2'] = df
   ....:
```

prove:

```
In [54]: [proc.open_files() for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.pid == os.getpid()]
Out[54]:
[[popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\en-US\\KernelBase.dll.mui', fd=-1),
  popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Max\\.ipython\\profile_default\\history.sqlite', fd=-1)]]
```

check whether `psutil` works properly at all (pay attention at the `D:\\temp\\aaa`):

```
In [55]: fd = open('d:/temp/aaa', 'w')

In [56]: [proc.open_files() for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.pid == os.getpid()]
Out[56]:
[[popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\en-US\\KernelBase.dll.mui', fd=-1),
  popenfile(path='D:\\temp\\aaa', fd=-1),
  popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Max\\.ipython\\profile_default\\history.sqlite', fd=-1)]]

In [57]: fd.close()

In [58]: [proc.open_files() for proc in psutil.process_iter() if proc.pid == os.getpid()]
Out[58]:
[[popenfile(path='C:\\Windows\\System32\\en-US\\KernelBase.dll.mui', fd=-1),
  popenfile(path='C:\\Users\\Max\\.ipython\\profile_default\\history.sqlite', fd=-1)]]
```

So using this technique you can debug your code and find the place where the number of open files goes crazy in your case

Comment: Thanks! I stopped the script by Ctrl+C and check with psutil, there is no file open! In fact I added logic to check if any files were open during the process - no files were ever opened after close! But after the script was stopped abnormally (without exception), couple of things are broken: cannot use psutil (AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'process_iter'), cannot open Excel file (IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: ...), autoreload is broken. Meanwhile, can read HDF file, can read pickle file. Don't even know where to look for the problem now...

Comment: I think you should try to find out what is happening when `the script was stopped abnormally (without exception)`... What does it mean `stopped abnormally`? How do you know that it's stopped and not hanging / writing / reading /waiting for some resources?

Comment: the script stopped and return to iPython console. no error msg at all. i can continue playing with comsole

Comment: @StanFish, i don't think i can help you not being able to see the loop where you reading Excel files and writing results to HDF5 files...

Comment: stopped abnormally meaning it shouldn't stopped before the loop finishes. if i open another console and run the script, it continues from where it stopped

Comment: let me add my loop to my question @MaxU

Comment: added. but i guess the question should be changed too - as we verified the files were indeed closed @MaxU

Comment: are using multiprocessing somewhere in your code? what `download_data()` is doing? how it's implemented?

Comment: there is no multiprocessing and the download_data is reading Bloomberg data. it was working normally for saving another type of data to pickle file, even with multiprocessing. so i was suspecting the problem lies in HDF5 files

Comment: @StanFish, try again your old solution saving to pickle files... Could it be the Bloomberg rejecting or redirecting to error page when you hit the limit or had too many requests?